# How to Configure Multi-Select-Lookup Control with respect to a lookup column in model driven app?

Tags: powerapps-modeldriven, dynamic365, model-driven-app

For Example I have two tables Departments and People where I want to add multiple People in Departments table through a lookup column.

How Can I achieve this through multi-select-lookup control?(assuming it as better solution)

What are the subscriptions required to make use of this advanced lookup feature, if the feature is not inbuilt in your model driven apps?

Is it possible to add multi-select-lookup control feature through external coding?

Any Leads regarding cost effective solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this PCF Control: https://pcf.gallery/polylookup/

I've created this control with more advanced features such as supporting N:N and custom N:N relationships, dynamic filtering (filter options depends on other fields on the form - which may be what you need), quick create, and more.

Hope this helps!